# Typescript Math documentation

Tags: typescript

Where can I find documention for the (built-in?) Math module?

In JavaScript I guess I used to use `Math.apply.max(Math.max, a)` to get the max value in the Array `a`, but the same in Typescript gives me a transpiling error that Math.apply doesn't exist. So how can I take a look at what Math does have? I couldn't find it in the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html).

Comment: It's easier to pass in the items of the array into the function using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator): `Math.max(...a);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no typescript documentation about built in js objects (as far as I'm aware), but you can find the definitions in the [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L543) (or [lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L543)).

What you want works, just not in the order you posted, it should be:

```
let list = [1, 2, 3];
let max = Math.max.apply(Math, list);
console.log(max); // 3
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20list%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%3B%0Alet%20max%20%3D%20Math.max.apply(Math%2C%20list)%3B%0Aconsole.log(max)%3B%20%2F%2F%203))

There's no `Math.apply`, but `apply` exists for all js functions, so it exists for `Math.max`.